# Want to all details of blob storage in one script

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-data-lake-gen2

Script:

```
$storageAccountKey = (Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName "RD-RDIPCloudMigration-AppResources-devtest" -AccountName "rdipstoragegen2").Value[0]
$ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "rdipstoragegen2" -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey
Get-AzDataLakeGen2ChildItem -Context $ctx -FileSystem "rdipdata" -Path "eval/raw/rdipclinicaltrial/data/warehouse/integrated/clntrl_reference_use.db" | export-csv "test.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

By using this I am only able to get details of file level, if I run this script again and again in each level the only i can get details of the file inside the folder.
FYI
[image]

Kindly help me to get one script by which i can get all the details include file inside the folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `-Recurse` switch within the [Get-AzDataLakeGen2ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/get-azdatalakegen2childitem?view=azps-9.0.1&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203) cmdlet that:

> Indicates if will recursively get the Child Item. The default is
> false.

Comment: is there anyhow to possible to hide the file extension of the file?

Comment: You can use the [GetFileNameWithoutExtension](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203) method for that